# What is the chemical result and resulting product of putting alabaster (calcium sulfate dihydrate) in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

As a sculptor, I use alabaster. I have tried using flowing water and I know it dissolves slowly. I want to try exhibiting a sculpture immersed in water either in a sealed or non sealed container. Are the resulting gases or solutions hazardous?

Answer (score 2):

Calcium sulfate dihydrate has a solubility in water of 0.26 g/100ml at 25 °C, so it dissolves slowly - you already know this. No gases will be evolved on dissolution so there is nothing to worry about there.

With respect to the resulting solution this is from [the Wikipedia page on Calcium Sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_sulfate):

> The calcium sulfate hydrates are used as a coagulant in products such as tofu. For the FDA, it is permitted in Cheese and Related Cheese Products; Cereal Flours; Bakery Products; Frozen Desserts; Artificial Sweeteners for Jelly & Preserves; Condiment Vegetables; and Condiment Tomatoes and some candies. It is known in the E number series as E516, and the UN's FAO knows it as a firming agent, a flour treatment agent, a sequestrant, and a leavening agent.

Not much to worry about there either, just dilute it with water for disposal and rinse off any that gets on your skin.